# Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred REACT and BACKBONE integration

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Iam getting the above error when I am trying to integrate REACT with my existing backbone project. So i follow the `**react.backbone**` plugin. i included below library in my lib folder and call it in `config.js` file

```
  "react": "libs/react.min",
    "react.backbone": "libs/react.backbone",
    "react-dom": "libs/react-dom",
    "browser": "libs/browser.min",
```

Now the below code i add in my backbone view file like below code. But at the time of rendering i am getting the below issue. Could you help me to solve this issue. where i missed what.

```
'use strict';
define(["jquery", 
        "backbone", 
        "common/utils", 
        "coreModule/views/base.view",'react','react-dom', 'react.backbone','browser'],
        function ($, 
                Backbone, 
                utils, 
                BaseView,
                React,reactDom,reactbackbone,browser) {
  var UserViewComponent = React.createBackboneClass({
                render: function() {
                    return (<div>test</div>);
                }
            });
            var UserView = React.createFactory(UserViewComponent);
            var userView = UserView();

// Mount your component directly
            React.render(userView, document.getElementById('test'));
});
```

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Probably your comment. Use `/* */` instead of `//`. When the file gets minified your double slash comment will comment out the rest of your code.

Comment: it's not working after change to /**/

Comment: @EricGuan Any decent minifier will be perfectly capable of interpreting a single line comment.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used React Backbone, but I can see from the [GitHub README](https://github.com/clayallsopp/react.backbone) that the render method is supposed to return JSX, not a plain string.

i.e. Change your render definition to:

```
render: function () {
    return <div>test</div>;
}
```

Further to that, it's a good idea to follow the advice of the warning and use the non-minified library to help you locate the source of the error.

Comment: Thanks for your response after update it ..i am getting a new error likeUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: You need to incorporate a JSX transpiler into your build step. If you're using babel, you can use the react preset. https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/